# How to add currency sign to all integers in a list of nested dictionaries

Tags: python-3.x

Given a list of nested dictionaries how can I add the currency locale to all the integer values using the locale module. My current solution works however I could not figure out how to make it work with nested dictionaries nor does it feel pythonic.

Example input

```
[
   {
      'name':'Tom',
      'total_salary': 70000,
      'salary': {
         'base':  65000,
         'bonus': 5000
      }
   },
   {
      'name':'Andrew',
      'total_salary': 50000,
      'salary': {
         'base':  45000,
         'bonus': 5000
       }
   }
]
```

Wanted output

```
[
   {
      'name':'Tom',
      'total_salary': '$70000',
      'salary': {
         'base':  '$65000',
         'bonus': '$5000'
      }
   },
   {
      'name':'Andrew',
      'total_salary': '$50000',
      'salary': {
         'base':  '$45000',
         'bonus': '$5000'
      }
   }
]
```

current solution

```
import locale
locale.setlocale( locale.LC_ALL, 'en_CA.UTF-8' )

def add_currency_locale(_list):
    new_list = []
    for d in _list:
        for k,v in list(d.items()):
            try:
                v = float(v)
                new_value = locale.currency(v, grouping=True)
                d[k] = new_value
            except:
                pass
        new_list.append(d)
    return new_list
```

Comment: Use fstring to assign value. change `d[k] = new_value` to `d[k] = '${}'.format(new_value)`

Comment: `list(d.items())` is unnecessary.  `for k,v in d.items():` works better because it doesn't need to waste cycles listing out the generator.

Comment: You code addresses only the `total_salary` key. It does not address the `salary` items. Did you notice that?

Comment: I agree however using ```d.items()```  will not work when iterating and modifying a dictionary at the same time. @PranavHosangadi

Comment: @chaudim that applies when you're adding / removing values from the dict. When you're simply modifying existing keys, it's not a problem

Comment: @JoeFerndz Yes I am aware. I am looking for solution to implement this is in the most pythonic way.

Comment: Also, your list is modified in-place. There's no need to append `d` to `new_list`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you have the line `locale.setlocale( locale.LC_ALL, 'en_CA.UTF-8' )`, I think you don't want to have the local currency symbol, but want it to always be `'$'`. If so, here is my solution, otherwise you can easily replace the line where I set `new_value`. I'm using recursion to correctly handle cases when you have nested lists or dictionaries (the code you've provided seems to not work for those cases, but according to the example input and output you need this. If you don't, remove the part with instance checking and replace the line `except ValueError:` with `except (ValueError, TypeError):`). Pay attention to the notes I left in the comments

```py
# Note: variable names with one leading underscore are "private" according to python code style.
# Use trailing underscore instead
def add_currency_locale(list_):
    new_list = []
    for d in list_:
        # Note: no need to convert `d.items()` to list: you can iterate over the original
        # object, and the conversion takes time
        for k, v in d.items():
            if isinstance(v, dict):
                # Because `add_currency_locale` only works with arrays, make an array of one
                # dictionary and then only use the first (and only) element of the returned list
                d[k] = add_currency_locale([v])[0]
            elif isinstance(v, list):
                d[k] = add_currency_locale(v)
            elif isinstance(v, (int, float)):
                d[k] = f'${v}'
            else:
                d[k] = v

        new_list.append(d)

    return new_list
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the `locale` module:

```
lst = [
    {
        'name':'Tom',
        'total_salary': 70000,
        'salary': {
            'base':  65000,
            'bonus': 5000
        }
    }, 
    {
        'name':'Andrew',
        'total_salary': 50000,
        'salary': {
            'base':  45000,
            'bonus': 5000
        }
    }
]

import locale
locale.setlocale( locale.LC_ALL, 'en_CA.UTF-8' )

def cnvrt(dct):
    for k, v in dct.items():
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            dct[k] = cnvrt(v)
        elif isinstance(v, int) or isinstance(v, float):
            dct[k] = locale.currency(v, grouping=True)
    return dct
print([cnvrt(i) for i in lst])
```

However, that won't give you your expected output which is just a `$` prepended to the value.

For that you can use.

```
def cnvrt(dct):
    for k, v in dct.items():
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            dct[k] = cnvrt(v)
        elif isinstance(v, int) or isinstance(v, float):
            dct[k] = f'${v}'
    return dct
print([cnvrt(i) for i in lst])
```

This works by recursively calling `cnvrt` if the value is a nested `dict`, otherwise, if it's an `int` or `float` it prepends a `$`. Since it's operating on the expectation of a `dict` object, you can use it in a nice `list` comprehension.

Finally, if you really want to you can handle `list`s with your function but IMO at this point it is doing too much.

```
def cnvrt(obj):
    if isinstance(obj, list):
        obj = [cnvrt(i) for i in obj]
    elif isinstance(obj, dict):
        for k, v in obj.items():
            if isinstance(v, dict) or isinstance(v, list):
                obj[k] = cnvrt(v)
            elif isinstance(v, int) or isinstance(v, float):
                obj[k] = f'${v}'
    return obj
print(cnvrt(lst))
```

Although, it works with inner `list`s and `dict`s as well, There is a lot going on which makes it hard to follow.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code to iterate through all the data elements and get the `$` symbol assigned to each value.

```
def add_curr(dict_list):
    new_lst = []
    for dic in dict_list:
        for k1, v1 in dic.items():
            if not isinstance(v1, dict):
                if isinstance(v1, (int, float)):
                    dic[k1] = '${}'.format(v1)
                else:
                    dic[k1] = v1
            else:    
                for k2,v2 in v1.items():
                    isinstance(v2, (int, float)):
                        dic[k1][k2] = '${}'.format(v2)
                    else:
                        dic[k1][k2] = v2
        new_lst.append(dic)

    return new_lst

add_curr(mylist)
```

You could decide to use the conversion part as a separate function and call it each time with a key and value

```
if isinstance(v1, (int, float)):
    dic[k1] = '${}'.format(v1)
else:
    dic[k1] = v1
```

This will give you the following dict:

```
[{'name': 'Tom', 
  'total_salary': '$70000', 
  'salary': 
          {'base': '$65000', 
           'bonus': '$5000'}}, 
 {'name': 'Andrew', 
  'total_salary': '$50000', 
  'salary': 
          {'base': '$45000', 
           'bonus': '$5000'}}]
```

Comment: Sorry, I was making my edits when your edit came thru. Incorporated your feedback. Thanks.

Comment: No worries! I figured that was the case so I left a comment :)